# How to Make WebView as Built In Bootstrap , Javascript Resource?

Tags: javascript, android, twitter-bootstrap, webview

My website needs bootstrap css of about 125KB, and Javascript of about 200KB - For Displaying the webpage properly.
I want to store the resource( bootstrap + js ) locally into the android webview source.

When i am trying to load my website on android webview , i want take the resource from local storage.

my webpage header codings :

```html
 <link href="source/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">        
    <script src="source/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="source/static/application.js"></script>
```

Comment: and your question is...?

Comment: i want take the resource from local storage